# How to benchmark a NAS from a Mac (Neither fio nor bonnie++ work)

Tags: performance, nas, benchmark

I want to test the performance of a NAS before and after I change its setup. I have found two tools for this, [fio](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html) and [bonnie++](https://doc.coker.com.au/projects/bonnie/).

The problem is that they are both broken on Mac right now (and have been for some time it seems). fio doesn't compile (Due to changes in XCode 8?) and bonnie fails to complete successfully (it fails on machines with more than 1 GB memory and also fails when it tries to clean up the files it created).

How can I test the performance of a NAS on a Mac? I am mostly interested in the relative performance, that is, how much the performance change when I make this change in configuration that I am about to try out, which I assume makes it easier?

(Or does it exist some static compiled fio/bonnie that works on current Mac OS?)

Comment: Is this really a question that's [in scope](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site?  At its heart, you want to determine the performance of a non-Apple device, the NAS.  This looks off topic to me.

Comment: @fsb Access performance can only be tested from a client which in this case seems to be a Mac

Comment: Did you check whether these tools are available via homebrew or macports?

Comment: @nohillside Bonnie 1.97 is available via MacPorts but doesn't work. I downloaded the source for Bonne 2.0x and compiled, but it hade the same problem. There *might* be a fork of Bonnie in Homebrew that *might* work but I would like to avoid installing HB for just one tool.

Comment: @nohillside If the question was about a software recommendation for doing this testing, I could see that being on-topic.  This question is about the performance of a NAS; even the OP states they're interested in the perf changes when making config changes.  The software is mentioned as an aside and is not the root of the question. I understand your point, I just disagree.

Comment: @fsb Do you think there are more people who know how to fix a Mac problem in a Mac forum or some other forum?

Comment: @d-b There is no Mac problem here, at least not as the question is currently written.  The problem, as stated, is how to test the performance of the NAS both before and after the config changes.  If the actual problem is for a software recommendation then the question and the tags should be changed to reflect that.

Comment: @fab Yes it is, since I need to run it on a Mac. That is the core question.

Answer (score 2):

Bonnie++ can be installed this way:

Download Bonnie++ 1.98 from here:

https://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/bonnie++-1.98.tgz

Extract the source code:

```
tar -xvzf bonnie++-1.98.tgz
```

Download the patch found here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/913b5a25087d2c64d3b6459635d5d64012b83042/bonnie%2B%2B/remove-large-file-support-macros.diff

Apply it to the source code using the `patch` utility:

```
cd bonnie++-1.98
patch < ../remove-large-file-support-macros.diff
```

Now configure and compile like usual:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. After a looong time, it quits with `Delete files in sequential order...Bonnie: drastic I/O error (rmdir): Directory not empty` although I at least could set `-r` to more than 1 GB.

Comment: What is the exact command line you start bonnie with? Are any of the paths on a networked file system? - If so which? (NFS, SMB, or?)

Comment: `$ bonnie++ -r 16384 -d /Volumes/tmp` - it is on a volume mounted via AFP.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with testing devices mounted via AFP (and possibly other network protocols). There are simply too many files in one directory to delete and for some reason bonnie chokes on that. I added `-n 1:0:0:100:` to my command, which, I think, run everything as default except it creates 100 directories and split the files it creates evenly among those directories. Now, with much fewer files in each directory, cleaning up them seemed to have worked fine.

Comment: Yes, that’s why I asked if it is networked. Bonnie is special in that it does a readdir() while changing things in the directory - works fine locally, but requires a networked file system to be fully POSIX compliant, which they often aren’t. There’s a patch around that makes it restart the readdir() (rewind) on every loop - makes it work with buggy NFS servers as well.

Comment: Well, well, cost me a few hours but at least I have a result now. You seem to know bonnie quite well, do you have any what's going on here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614707/output-from-bonnie-doesnt-match-up ? Thank you.

Comment: BTW, I have upvoted your answer. If you also include the information about this second patch, I will mark it as the accepted answer.